# mysql.connector method chaining error (ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists)

Tags: mysql-python, method-chaining

```
import mysql.connector
mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user='xxxx',password='xxxx',database="xxxx").cursor().execute("show tables")
```

Error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "xx:\xx\xx.py", line 10, in 
> mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user='xxxx',password='xxxx',database="xxxx").cursor().execute("show tables")
> File "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 536, in execute
> if not self._connection:
> ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists

I know if I write it this way there is no error :

```
import mysql.connector
database=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user='xxxx', password='xxxx',database="xxxx")
cursor=database.cursor()
cursor.execute("show tables")
```

Why can't I chain my code? Why is it like this? Any help much appreciated <3!

Comment: I'm getting this same problem without chaining it.